# reading urls from a file to be used with CURLOPT_URL

Tags: c, libcurl

Im working on a small problem. I am new to C. The issue I am having is reading urls from a file to be used with CURLOPT_URL. i don't seem to be able to do it. In the example code below i have used "http://10.10.10.10/" this is where i would like to have urls loaded from a file... I have tried fgets to read line and have "line" assigned were "http://10.10.10.10/" is in the example.

```
        FILE* fp;
        char buffer[255];
        fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

        while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp)) {
            CURLM *m_curl;
            CURLMcode res;
            m_curl = curl_multi_init();
            curl_multi_setopt(m_curl, CURLMOPT_PIPELINING, 1L); 

            CURL *curl[MAX_PIPELINE_REQ];

            for(i=0; i<pipeline_req; i++){ 
                curl[i] = curl_easy_init();
                if(!curl[i])
                    err("Something went wrong", 0);
                res = curl_easy_setopt(curl[i], CURLOPT_URL, buffer);
```

Comment: Is the problem reading from the file? Or is the problem calling `curl_easy_setopt`? What is `url`? How is it initialized? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I have edited the example. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Not much clearer, except that this seems to be more of how you're handling files and the reading from the files, than with cURL itself. So please make a [mcve] that shows how you read the file.

Comment: Did you check these examples- https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Comment: I have. I have not found anything I can put to use yet. maybe a little to complex for me. I will go through them again and see if i can find something to work with.

Comment: It'd be better if you showed the entire code and if you told us what libcurl returns when you try this. I **guess** you have a newline at the end of the URL string which makes it an illegal URL and libcurl returns an error to you saying that...